# How to make divs stop moving when they hit each other while resizing the window? (positioned with percentages)

Tags: jquery, html, css

For example:

```
HTML
<nav>
     <div class="first"></div>
     <div class="second"></div>
<nav>

CSS
.first{
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 15px;
width: 180px;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
top: -1px;
}

.second{
position: absolute;
left: 30%;
top:14px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

What happens is when you resize the window and .second moves to overlap the fixed .first. Is it possible to make the .second div stop moving once it hits .first?

Comment: Yes, don't use absolute positioning, use FLOATS.

Comment: It depends on what exactly you want to happen when said point is reached. do you want the parent div to stop getting smaller? do you want the 2nd div to start getting smaller? do you want the 2nd div to wrap to the next line? The answer to *"Is it possible"* is usually Yes.

Comment: I want the left div (.first) to stay the same, and the second div on the right to resize as it hits the first one, instead of overlapping it.

Answer (score 0):

```
.first{
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
}

.second{
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    width: 50%;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```